# Visualising moderator effects in multiple moderator models

Tags: multiple-regression

I work with a model with four moderators (i.e. multiple additive moderation). Now, I would like to visualize and probe each individual interaction. However, programs such as PROCESS (Hayes) and others, only allow one or two moderators at the same time (e.g., Hayes;model 2). Can anyone explain if it's possible to visualize interactions when working with more than two moderators?

Thanks,